# Profile image in Autocomplete Dropdown - Rails 4, Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, carrierwave

I'm trying to display a users profile image, along with their username in an autocomplete dropdown.

The autocomplete functionality works fine, I'm just having trouble displaying the actual image in the dropdown. I get the image URL instead of the image.

I'm using carrierwave for image uploading and jQuery-UI for autocomplete.

**users_controller.rb:**

```
def index
  @users = User.order(:username).where("username like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
  render json: @users.map{ |user| "#{user.username} - #{user.user_photo}"}
end
```

**The form:**

```
<% if policy(@list).add_collaborators? %>
  <h3>Add Collaborator</h3>
  <%= form_for [@list, @collaboration] do |f| %>
    <%= label_tag "Enter collaborator username" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :username, nil, data: {users_source: users_path} %>
    <%= f.submit "Add collaborator" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Image of what I'm getting:**

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhjcd.png)

I feel like there's a pretty easy solution for this, what am I missing?

Thanks for any help anyone can send my way!

**EDIT:**
Please let me know if anyone needs any more info about my project.